# CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY when using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR to create buffer

Tags: opencl

I was previously allocating a buffer using the iterator method of the opencl 1.2 wrapper. However for performance reasons I have tried to provide a host pointer to the memory already allocated. However when specifying a buffer with this I get a CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY error on clCreateBuffer call.

This code previously worked when I had my memory allocated as std::vector and provided the buffer with the iterator method e.g

```
std::vector<int> mem;
mem.resize( 256*256*256, 0);
_d_currentmap= cl::Buffer(*_context,
            mem.begin(), mem.end(), false);
```

`_d_currentmap` is created and doesn't throw any errors. I actually create two buffers of the same size.

Following [this intel article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-the-most-from-opencl-12-how-to-increase-performance-by-minimizing-buffer-copies-on-intel-processor-graphics), I am trying to migrate to a zero copy paradigm as I am deploying intel HD graphics which shares mem with the cpu

First I initialise memory that is to be shared, _map1 and _map2 are initilised.:

```
int size = 256*256*256;
int* _map1 = (int*)aligned_alloc(4096, sizeof(int)*size);
int* _map2 = (int*)aligned_alloc(4096, sizeof(int)*size);
memset((void*)_map1, 0, size*sizeof(int));
memset((void*)_map2, 0, size*sizeof(int));
```

I then want to swap between these objects alternatively:

```
int size = 256*256*256*sizeof(int);
int* currptr, newptr;
switch( newmapnumber)
{
case 1:
    memset(_map1, 0, size);
    newptr= _map1;
    currptr= _map2;
    break;
case 2:
    memset(_map2, 0, size);
    newptr =_map2;
    currptr =_map1;
    break;
}
_mapSeq++;

try{
    cl::CommandQueue queue(*_context, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE);
    _d_newmap = cl::Buffer(*_context, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, size*sizeof(int),(void*) newptr);
    _d_currentmap = cl::Buffer(*_context, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, size*sizeof(int), (void*)currptr);
    queue.finish();          
 }
 catch (cl::Error err) {
    std::cout << "Exception\n";
    std::cerr
     << "ERROR: "
     << err.what()
     << "("
     << err.err()
     << ")"
     << std::endl;
     exit(1);
 }
```

This will return

```
Exception
ERROR: clCreateBuffer(-6)
```

Which is a CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY error as defined in cl.h

Answer (score 0):

Okay, no-one would have got this, as I didn't add the key piece of information. The int size changed in value between the two blocks.

As shown in the top code block

```
   int size = 256*256*256;
```

however in the bottom block I specified a local variable size (for use in the cl::Buffer declarations) to be

```
   int size=256*256*256*sizeof(int);
```

Thus in the declaration of the buffer I am multiplying size by sizeof(int) again:

```
 _d_newmap = cl::Buffer(*_context, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, size*sizeof(int),(void*) newptr);
```

causing buffer overwrites and a bunch of other grief.

Comment: Just an observation: if you plan on executing that "swap between these objects alternatively" code in a loop, i'd suggest you move CL-object creation (queues and buffers) outside the loop, and swap cl::Buffer pointers instead. Otherwise you're creating and releasing a bunch of CL objects inside the try block - which you may assume is cheap, but i assure you it's not, at least with some OpenCL implementations. Even if it is relatively cheap on Intel, it's unnecessary. You can reuse queues and buffers.

Comment: @mogu, I did get a performance benefit from doing the above, however you were right, in that buffer creation is very costly. I halved my cpu usage by not creating buffers in the loop.